# Инициализация внутренних структур. Написание собственного контрола

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, usercontrol

Сделал свой компонент наподобие грида. Класс унаследован от `Control`. Внутри есть двумерный массив из ячеек `Cell` (тоже собственный класс). В зависимости от количества столбцов/строк тот массив инициализируется при первой отрисовке `OnPaint`

```
if (_cells == null)
    InitCells();

private void InitCells()
{
    _cells = new Cell[ColumnCount, RowCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < RowCount; j++)
        {
            _cells[i, j] = new Cell(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Данный компонент размещен на форме. Соответственно `ColumnCount` и `RowCount` присваиваются значения в `InitializeComponents()` той самой формы. Однако при запуске формы хотелось бы заполнить грид, а это зависит напрямую от инициализации массива ячеек. Событие `Load` формы происходит до `InitializeComponents`. Отсюда ошибка. Если инициализировать массив в конструкторе, то тогда `ColumnCount` и `RowCount` не присвоятся значения и массив будет пустой.

Comment: InitializeComponents() обычно в конструкторе вызывается. В этом случае не могут какие-то там события срабатывать раньше или позже - объекта нет.
Уточните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не вынести ваш код в отдельный метод, заполнение грида так же в отдельный метод и вызывать их в конструкторе после InitializeComponent()? Например, пара хелперов, в которые передается Grid как параметр?

```
InitializeComponent();
InitCells();
FillGrid(this.grid1);
```